# Dividing by infinities while doing ratio of areas in probability

Tags: probability

The sides of a rectangle are chosen at random, each less than $10$ cm, all such lengths being equally likely. The chance that the diagonal of the rectangle is less than $10$ cm is..?

The solution to this::

[image]

So if you write the constraint $ x^2 +y^2 <10$, where $x,y$ are side lengths of rectangles, we get a circle  as its solution set but we only take a quadrant as sides should have positive signs.

Now, we take square because that is satisfy that max constraint $x=10, y=10$.

Then, we divide area of sector by square to find probability.

My problem: There are infinite points in any given area, so when we divide area to find probability, aren't we technically dividing infinities? I mean why is area equivalent to number of points constrained?

A resolution from a friend: he defines a density function, and says that number points = density * area, but the problem I have with this approach is, this density function should be infinite then.

Now why does this method for solving work at all then? Like why does this give right result in the end?

Comment: This is smaller than an intended answer, so I'll keep it in the comments. The way you are thinking about probability is correct, although the treatment is slightly wrong. Your definition of probability is $P(A)=\text{required measure of subset from total sample space}/\text{measure of sample space}. Observe that, if your sample space is finite, then this collapses to the old definition of probability ( ratio of number of possibilities after constraint and total number of possibilities ). Here, your sample space is not finite, and you can observe that your subset is also not finite...

Comment: ...(contd.) The measure here is the area of the subset and sample space under consideration. Thus your probability is the division of two areas and not infinite number of points.

Comment: You might be interested in this video by 3blue1brown in which he discusses probability density functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA4JkHKZM50&t=3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we subdivide the given area into $100$ squares, we can count the number of squares inside the quadrant of the circle. If the square is fully in the shaded region, count it as $1$ square, and if not, count it as $0$ squares.

This gives us a rough approximation for the percentage covered, but it is not exact since we have not included areas which are inside the circle but are not in the subdivided square. If we repeat the process but with $100^2$ squares or $1000^3$ squares, we can better approximate the boundary of the circle, and this will give us better and better approximations.

When the number of squares approaches infinity, this will still give us a ratio of areas, but now the subdivided squares are infinitely small. This means we can avoid dividing infinity by infinity by using limits, and still reach a percentage which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

With your logic, then any area is infinity.

Just like you calculate any circle area as $\pi r^2$ and square as $s^2$, you do the same thing here. Yes, there *are* infinitely many points, but they equal a finite area. You don't say that the area of a circle with radius $1$ is infinity, or any radius for that matter.

(Also side note: the area of the circle is $x^2+y^2<100$, not $10$.)

-FruDe